# Create custom "read" Intent like GetCurrentLocation

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit, sirishortcuts

I'm creating shortcuts for a communication app. In this app there is a presence state (available, dnd, ...). I implemented an intent to set said presence state which worked fine. I created a "read" intent which just returns the currently set state, which works, but i can't pass the result to the next action.

For simplification and testing i created another intent just return a string, trying to process it, but i'm still unable to do that. My intent has no input parameters.

What am i missing? My Goal would be an interaction like `Get Current Location` offers.

```
class Return5IntentHandler: NSObject, Return5IntentHandling {
    func handle(intent: Return5Intent, completion: @escaping (Return5IntentResponse) -> Void) {
        completion(.success(result: "5"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic case of searching for hours, writing a question only to find the answer 30min later yourself...

One has to explicitly set the output, which is the passed on value for following actions.

[image]